# Create BoltProtocolTokenRegistry.asset failed, using Photon Bolt in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I have some custom tokens working with Bolt. When I try to click in the menu "PhotonBolt/Protocol Tokens Registry", a pop up message asked if I want to create a new Protocol Token Registry. I chose yes, then the following error appears.

What should I do about it? Thank you!

"UnityException: Creating asset at path C:\Developer\UnityProjects\CardGame\Assets\Photon\PhotonBolt\resources\BoltProtocolTokenRegistry.asset failed.

Photon.Bolt.Editor.CustomInspector.BoltProtocolTokenRegistryEditor.Open () (at :0)

"
[image]

[image]

This is how I import the new version:

1 Use Package Manager to import everything I could in 1.3.2 version.

2 Deleted Plugins/JsonDotNet.

3 Still encountered some compiling errors(which is solved after re-open the project later). So deleted the whole Assets/Photon directory.

4 Use Package Manager to import only Photon directory, nothing under Plugins, Packages, Scenes, Gizmos.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why its erroring, however this work around helped me

1. Find and select the script `BoltProtocolTokenRegistry`
2. Create an instance using the inspector menu [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuEsj.png)
3. Move the created asset instance to `Assets\Photon\PhotonBolt\resources\`

From there you should be able to refresh and used the Token Registry without issue